# iOS >> CoreData >> Is There an Apple Default Tool to Read the SQLite Table?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm developing an app that uses Core Data. To open the SQLite table (for testing purposes) I use an app called Liya.

Does Apple have a default app to open and read this type of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an Apple default way of opening a DB, you have to go with 3rd party software.

Comment: Core Data Editor (can handle SQLite, XML and Binary stores): http://thermal-core.com/CoreDataEditor

Answer (score 1):

Apple includes sqlite3 with OSX (maybe command line tools?). You can read the core data sqlite file (from the command line) with `sqlite3 dbfile`.